# Can ping ubuntu server, but not connect with putty

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty, ubuntu-16.04

I'm just wondering if this is common. And if there is a way around this problem.

I have a webserver at home running on ubuntu 16.04. I manage this through putty.

My problem happened when I was managing my server via putty. My computer did a update/restart while I was eating.
After this I cannot connect to the server via putty anymore. I can ping it. And the webserver is up and running.

Maybe the session I had via putty before the computer shutdown didn't close the session correct. I'm just guessing now.

Is there a workaround without fysically restart the webserver?

Appreciate any ideas on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely 1 of 2 things - sshd is not running or the firewall has changed to disallow connections on port 22.

Uf you have physical access to the server, try restarting ssh with

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

If that does not work, try adding a firewall rule to the running system

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi, The restart of ssh didnt do anything. But the second command worked. But after restart of server I got the same problme again which was solved by entering the command again. Do I have to go to the server after each restart to do this command? I had the server running for more than one year, and now it starts to make a fuss.

Comment: So we know the problem is that the firewall is blocking incoming requests on port 22, and we need to allow it.   Depending on your setup and skill, there are different ways to fix this.  You could add the command to /etc/rc.local before the "exit 1" (but that is not a good way of doing things).  If you use UFW (which is installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04) then the best way to do this would probably be to type "sudo ufw allow 22"